# share Neo4j Bloom saved query

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, bloom

I am currently on the free AuraDB version of Neo4j. From my Neo4j Desktop, I opened Bloom and created a number of Saved Cypher (Search phrase and Scene actions) so that non-technical people in the team can simply click on these and find relevant information

The question is: Is there any way I can easily share these saved Search Phrase and Scene Actions to anyone?

If not, do I have to upgrade to neo4j Professional?

Comment: yes, you can save your search phrases and scenes (called Perspective).

Comment: totally missed that simple solution. Many thanks @jose_bacoy